# Extracting data from a JOOQ query when using Jasync

Tags: kotlin, jooq, jasync-sql

When using JOOQ to create the queries and Jasync to execute the queries, how does one get the RowData back into JOOQ Records?

This is my notransaction helper which does a suspendable non-async query

```
    override suspend fun <T> notransaction(f: suspend (ConnectionPool<*>) -> T): T {
        val cdf = CompletableDeferred<T>()
        try {
            GlobalScope.launch {
                cdf.complete(f(connectionPool))
            }
        } catch (e: Throwable) {
            log.error(e.message ?: "", e)
            cdf.completeExceptionally(e)
        }
        return cdf.await()
    }
```

I have defined two tables with their relevant records:

```
class ListingRecord : CustomRecord<ListingRecord>(listing)
class ListingTable : CustomTable<ListingRecord>(DSL.name("listing")) {

    val id: TableField<ListingRecord, UUID> = createField(DSL.name("id"), SQLDataType.UUID)
    val title: TableField<ListingRecord, String> = createField(DSL.name("title"), SQLDataType.VARCHAR)

    companion object {
        val listing = ListingTable()
    }

    override fun getRecordType(): Class<out ListingRecord> {
        return ListingRecord::class.java
    }

}

class ListingImageRecord : CustomRecord<ListingImageRecord>(listingImage)
class ListingImageTable : CustomTable<ListingImageRecord>(DSL.name("listing_image")) {

    val id: TableField<ListingImageRecord, UUID> = createField(DSL.name("id"), SQLDataType.UUID)
    val name: TableField<ListingImageRecord, String> = createField(DSL.name("name"), SQLDataType.VARCHAR)
    val listingId: TableField<ListingImageRecord, UUID> = createField(DSL.name("listing"), SQLDataType.UUID)

    companion object {
        val listingImage = ListingImageTable()
    }

    override fun getRecordType(): Class<out ListingImageRecord> {
        return ListingImageRecord::class.java
    }

}
```

Generated an SQL query

```
    val dsl = DSL.using(SQLDialect.POSTGRES)
    val query = dsl.select(
        listing.id, listing.title,
        listingImage.id, listingImage.listingId
    ).from(listing).leftJoin(listingImage).on(listing.id.eq(listingImage.listingId))
```

[image]

how does one map the RowData back to JOOQ?
Is there some way to get a map of columns in the select statement and their indices
or some other way to map results back?
I'm assuming i need to map it back to a Record somehow so that i can do

```
listing.id.get(ListingRecord)
```

Comment: From Lukas: It should be possible to implement this without too much hassle:

<R extends Record> Flux<R> magic(ResultQuery<R> query);

The implementation then works for all jOOQ queries, and is reasonably type safe.